# Running a python file with www-data returning permission denied

Tags: php, sh

I am wanting to restart a python script from PHP.

I have created the shell script:

```
# kill script
`which pkill` -f "$script"

# start script
`which python` "$script" > /dev/null &
```

when I execute this with www-data (PHP [`shell_exec()`]) I get the error:

> /usr/bin/python: can't open file '`$script`': [Errno 13] Permission denied

and the permissions of the '`$script`' is:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data
```

The script is not in `/var/www` and nor do I want it to be.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the directory where `$script` is stored? User www-data will need to have 'x' permission in order to see what is inside the directory.

Comment: @yivi it is not clear what you are saying is not clear?

Comment: @Craig parent directory: `drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data`

Comment: You tagged this question PHP and Python. there is no PHP nor Python code in this question.

Comment: Both php and python are used in my code as applications.

Comment: `which python` is used in my question as well as "I execute this with www-data (PHP)"

Comment: Your question doesn't include PHP nor Python code. It shoulnd't be tagged with those languages tags... Can't be any more clearer than that. Either relevant code is missing, or the wrong tags are being used.

Comment: well that is not true.

Comment: top 10 most famous php question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api can't see php

Comment: that's a seven years old question. the standards have changed **considerably**

Comment: You should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging. I'm not attacking you, just trying to help.

Comment: Again, there is no PHP. No PHP expert can help you with this question as stated. There is no reason to tag this question as PHP.

Answer (score -1):

My solution was to allow root (sudo) to python by adding this to visudo:

```
www-data ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/python
```